# Adding a Gradient Layer in Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a requirement to add a gradient on top of a background image.  I have already set my image as the background of the page but I can't figure out how best to add the Gradient in Android.  I have done the following with iOS:

```
public class GradientContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement == null) // perform initial setup
        {
            var page = e.NewElement as GradientContentPage;
            var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();
            gradientLayer.Frame = View.Bounds;
            gradientLayer.Locations = new NSNumber[] { 0.2,0.8} ;
            gradientLayer.Colors = new CGColor[] { page.StartColor.ToCGColor(), page.EndColor.ToCGColor() };
            View.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradientLayer, 0);

        }
    }
}
```

I know how to create a gradient with a Drawable with Android but I cannot figure out how to add it as a layer.  If it's possible I would like to inject a new Relative Layout during render time by using a custom Renderer but I can't figure out how to do that.  Keep in mind I need to keep the existing background image and I just want to lay a gradient over the top.

Is there a way to dynamically insert an additional layout and render time?  Or is there a different approach I should be taking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected override void DispatchDraw(global::Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
{
    base.DispatchDraw(canvas);

    var gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, Height, 
        Color.FromRgba(255, 255, 255, 100).ToAndroid(), 
        Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 100).ToAndroid(), 
        Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);

    var paint = new Android.Graphics.Paint() {
        Dither = true,
    };
    paint.SetShader(gradient);

    canvas.DrawPaint(paint);
}
```

To have all controls on top of your gradient just put `base.DispatchDraw(canvas);` on bottom:

```
protected override void DispatchDraw(global::Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
{
    var gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, Height, 
        Color.FromRgba(255, 255, 255, 100).ToAndroid(), 
        Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 100).ToAndroid(), 
        Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);

    var paint = new Android.Graphics.Paint() {
        Dither = true,
    };
    paint.SetShader(gradient);

    canvas.DrawPaint(paint);

    base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```